# decompressing a compressed string

Tags: string, python-3.x, compression

My question is that I don't know where to go now with the code I have to create a decompress code. I get the error (TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str') and assume its because I'm not multiplying the string correctly. Also, I can't use lists, just string manipulation for this assignment

Just as an example, the output's suppose to look like this-> cat2dog1qwerty3 -> catcatdogqwertyqwertyqwerty

Function:

```
def decompress(compressed_in):
new_word = True
char_holder = ""
decompressed_out = ""
for char in compressed_in:
    if char.isalpha and new_word:
        char_holder += char
        new_word = False
    elif char.isalnum:
        decompressed_out += char * char_holder
        new_word = True
return decompressed_out
```

Main:

```
# Import
from compress import decompress

# Inputs
compressed_in = str(input("Enter a compressed string: "))  # compressed

# Outputs
decompressed_out = decompress(compressed_in)
print(decompressed_out)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is apparently a homework assignment, I won't give you the code, but here are several problems I see with what you're presented.

1. Indentation. This is probably an artifact of copying-and-pasting, but every line after the `def` should be indented.
2. Not calling functions. When you write `char.isalpha`, that probably isn't doing what you want it to. `.isalpha()` is a function, so you need to call it with parentheses, like `char.isalpha()`.
3. `isalnum()` is probably not the function you want. That checks if something is a letter or a number, but you've already checked for letters, so you probably want the function that checks if something is a number. This isn't strictly necessary, since the other `if` condition will still trigger first, but it's something you could get marked down for.
4. You never clear `char_holder`. It looks like you meant to, since you have a boolean `new_word` that you keep track of, but you aren't using it properly. At some point, you should be doing `char_holder = char` (ie. not `+=`). I'll let you decide where to put that logic.
5. Finally, for the error you're getting. You are correct that you are not multiplying things together correctly. Think about what the types are in the multiplication statement, and what values the variables would have. For example, in the first pass, `char_holder` would be equal to `'cat'`, and `char` would be equal to `'3'`. Try typing `'3' * 'cat'` into a Python interpreter and see what happens. It should be evident from here what you need to do to fix this.

Comment: hmm, I fixed some things and get a blank answer instead, which is better than an error.  I also removed new_word entirely cause I dont think I need it. I'm left with http://imgur.com/a/FuJ5h

Comment: You still aren't actually calling `isalpha()`. By not including the parentheses after it, you're basically just asking Python whether or not it exists, which is always true. So your `elif` branch never happens. Also, the statement `int(char)` by itself doesn't do anything. You have to assign the result of that to some variable.

Comment: ur right, I fixed those two errors and got the code working. Thanks for ur help. Just wondering, how would i edit the code to make it work with 2-digit numbers or more like cat22dog14

Comment: Just like you have a temporary variable named `char_holder`, you could create a similar one named `num_holder` or something which holds your number temporarily, and each time you encounter a subsequent digit, you expand `num_holder` with it. That would then require some more logic to know when you're done seeing digits (ie. when you see letters again), and probably some logic at the end to deal with digits that occurred at the end of the string (without any letters after them).

Comment: Alright I tried this for fun, and I don't really know how to start a second loop inside the the first_loop where char left off. I tried using len, but probably did that wrong also. I added the things in my code with red paint, and am now using num_holder http://imgur.com/a/k7Vyh

Comment: The way, I would do it, I wouldn't use a second loop. Rather, when the code reaches a character, I would check if there is some value in `num_holder`, and if there is, I would use that value to create the decompressed string. Then clear `char_holder` and `num_holder` and keep going as usual. This will create a bit of a problem, however, since there won't be any character after the last number, so you'd have to add some code at the end to do the final decompression.

Comment: Ah i see, that way sounds much more efficient. How would you continue through a loop starting from where char left off anyway. Wouldn't it just need to check the second value after it using the string function like [1], i assume

Comment: Checking just the one character after it wouldn't work in general, since the number could be only one digit long, or more than two digits long. The correct way to tell when a number stops is when either you hit another letter, or you hit the end of the string. Here's how I would write it: http://imgur.com/a/suMZQ

Comment: So I wouldn't be able to use a nested loop since I'm restricted to those conditions I made. That makes sense. The way you wrote it makes a ton of sense. Wouldn't not matter if you changed ur second if statement to elif jw, regardless it would probably be the same thing. Anyway Thanks for keeping me company and answering my question! :D